# UrlFetchApp.fetch() skip on empty cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a script that gets an image url from a cell in Google Sheets and adds that image to a template in Google Docs. However, when the cell is empty, the script crashes:

```
var beforePhoto1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[14]).getBlob();
```

Really new to programming and would appreciate anyones help as to how to prevent the above code from crashing in the event a cell is empty

Comment: I thought that in your question, when you provide your current whole script for replicating your issue and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there are two options:

1. Check the value before:

```
if (row[14] != '') {
  var beforePhoto1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[14]).getBlob();
} else {
  console.log('row[14] was empty');
  var beforePhoto1 = 'default_value';
}

// rest code
```

2. Try to use the value and skip any error with `try/catch`:

```
try {
  var beforePhoto1 UrlFetchApp.fetch(row[14]).getBlob();
} catch(e) {
  console.log('row[14] was empty');
  var var beforePhoto1 = 'default_value';
}

// rest code
```